# WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114 : mojolang

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, modular, mojo, mojolang

I am trying to download mojolang from the website

https://developer.modular.com/download

It says ***"Install Ubuntu 22.04 for WSL and open it."***

[image]

I tried installing `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS` from the website:

https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/ubuntu-22042-lts/9PN20MSR04DW

I was able to download it from the website.

Once I tried to open it from the terminal (Windows Powershell). I get this error:

> WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114

> Error: 0x80370114 The operation could not be started because a required feature is not installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the solution. I writing here if someone in future find this problem.

Go To `Control Panel` -> `Turn Windows features on or off`

Check `Virtual Machine Platform` and `Windows Subsystem for Linux`

[image]

Restart your computer after doing the above steps.